# 2D array of chars, scan and printout like table

Tags: c, arrays, char, 2d

i need 2D array of char for late calculation, but this ends the program after 4 char. What is incorect? Its work with strings, correctly so i expect smthing with scanf will be  wrong. Can somone tell me how it could be and WHY it could be like that? Thks. (C::B,W)

```
char map[height][width];
for (i=0;i<height;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<width;j++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&map[i][j]);
    }
}

for (i=0;i<height;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<width;j++)
    {
        printf("%c",map[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: It would help to see a bit more of your code where you give values to height and width.

Comment: Do you have entered without newline?

Comment: Its work with numbers corectly so its doesnt metter.

Comment: Yes i do. Its end after 4 char  3x3, 8-4x4 and 12-5v5

Answer (score 0):

> scanf("\n %c",&map[i][j]);

Scanf doesn't remove white spaces if you are using %c

Comment: What are white spaces?